# Is there a query to select a column whose name is stored in another table?

Tags: sql, select, teradata

I have two tables - tblColName and tblData

tblColNames has the list of names of columns of tblData that I want to select.

```
tblColNames
-----------
Var1
Var2
Var8
Var9
```

I only want to select the columns from tblData whose names are present in tblColNames.

Is there a Teradata SQL query to do this?

Comment: That's a basic `JOIN` or `WHERE myColumnWithName IN (SELECT ...)` query. Have you tried something yet?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I read it as he means `SELECT var1, var2, var8, var9 from tblData` where the list var1-9 is generated dynamically, which isn't a `JOIN` or a `WHERE` AFAICS.

Comment: @Rup  Yes that is what I meant. Not a JOIN.

Comment: https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/what-is-dynamic-sql this can be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this task you have to use dynamic SQL. The required commands are to be invoked in a procedure and basically look like the following (this is a `DB2`example I once wrote, but the principles should be similar in any dialect):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DYNAMIC_TABLE_ACCESS
(IN TableName VARCHAR(40), IN ColName VARCHAR(40))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
READS SQL DATA
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC DYNAMIC_TABLE_ACCESS
BEGIN
        DECLARE V_DYNAMIC VARCHAR(200);
        DECLARE V_SQL VARCHAR(200);

        DECLARE V_CUR CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR V_DYNAMIC;

        SET V_SQL='SELECT ' CONCAT ColName CONCAT ' AS ColName FROM ' CONCAT TableName;

        PREPARE V_DYNAMIC FROM V_SQL;
        OPEN V_CUR;
END
```

The idea is to create a string `V_SQL` containing the SQL-statement with a dynamically selected column- and table-name, which is then invoked via `PREPARE` and by the `OPEN` cursor command.

As a result, you see the entries of the specified column and table printed on the screen.